# CSS SVGator animations and multiple classes

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svgator

**The premise:**
There are 8 tabs (with JS) to toggle the associated content wrappers via **display:none** --> **display:block**. Those content wrappers have animated SVGs inside them and they cause issues.
Essentially, if the tab is active, the associated content wrapper should display and the SVG animation should play. Once another tab is activated, the previous content wrapper and the SVG animation should reset.

I've created some animations in SVGator, yet failed to put them to work due to a few reasons:

1. Having 8 tabs, each containing only one of the 8 SVGs means only the active tab should animate. This is obviously not the case and they would all animate even if invisible.
2. So I thought using the 'scroll into view' would fix it, coupled with switching of the tabs. However, since the tabs turn the SVG respective wrappers from display:none to display:block, the animations fail to play at all. (I've tried to research the keyframes and diplay:block properties for that matter...)
3. So I thought I'd turn to *CSS **only*** animation, compile all keyframes into a .css file and would toggle the class to activate the respective keyframes.

Currently, I think that using the 3. approach is the only viable solution here. Yet, my JS is not strong and seemingly failed me somewhere =(
Could someone please help me fix it?
Bonus query: any other suggestions how this could be all put together to work?

```
<div class="taps">
     <button class="taplinks" onclick="openTap(event, 'One', SVG-1)" id="defaultOpen">Button 1</button>
     <button class="taplinks" onclick="openTap(event, 'Two', SVG-2)">Button 2</button>
     <button class="taplinks" onclick="openTap(event, 'Three', SVG-3)">Button 3</button>
   </div> 

   <div id="One" class="tapcontent">
      <svg id="SVG-1" . . .rest of the generated code (without CSS keyframes). . . </svg>
   </div> 
   <div id="Two" class="tapcontent">
      <svg id="SVG-2" . . .rest of the generated code (without CSS keyframes). . . </svg>
   </div> 
   <div id="Three" class="tapcontent">
      <svg id="SVG-3" . . .rest of the generated code (without CSS keyframes). . . </svg>
   </div> 


JavaScript: 

function openTap(evt, TapName, svgName) {
  var i, tapcontent, taplinks;
  tapcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tapcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tapcontent.length; i++) {
    tapcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  taplinks = document.getElementsByClassName("taplinks");
  for (i = 0; i < taplinks.length; i++) {
    taplinks[i].className = taplinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(TapName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  var element = document.getElementById(TapName);
  element.classList.add("reveal");
}
document.getElementById(svgName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  var element = document.getElementById(svgName);
  element.classList.add("animate");
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

I've used this JS successfully without SVGs (used to be just images), so switching the tabs works, yet for some reason by adding the same logic to SVG `element.classList.add(animate);` doesn't seem to work.
NB: I've renamed some of the parameters, as I tend to use weird to the outsiders logic and naming xD

Comment: Can you give us an example in jsfiddle or codepen to replicate? Thanks

Comment: I would, but it is so incredibly chunky... I'm sure it's some mistake in JS since I'm horrible with it still. I will try to compose a codepen, I was sure it is doable without it in this case, sowwy

Comment: Okay, very messy and not pleasant to read, anyway, here it is: 

[CodePen monstrosity](https://codepen.io/_kingwasabi/pen/Vwrmjgv)

Also, I had to switch the SVGs path IDs to classes, so that I can add the same classes to the respective button (since ID does not support spaces). It is very tedious, besides the code not working - is there a better way to call such animation on button click? SVGator does not provide much info regarding this =(

Comment: Also, there are a few options when exporting from SVGator: 
1) Javascripted (options include: onload, onclick on the svg, on scroll into view)
2) CSS only, which I chose, since JS seems impossible to tailor to the needs of a having a button. Am I wrong? (CSS on hover also an option)

Comment: Also, `var element = document.getElementsByClassName(svgName);
  element.classList.add("animate");` gives an error on codepen, by saying "Cannot read properties of undefined", but it seemingly worked with getElemenetById previously

Answer (score 0):

There is now a way to control the animation programmatically.
Export your SVGs using "Animation start: Programmatic" and start the animation when needed.

I you want to use JS, you could easily detach the element from the DOM tree and attach it when the content wrapper becomes visible. That resets the CSS animation.